# The requested URL /apk-download/ was not found on this server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have migrated one of my client's sites to Linode. Now the homepage is working and the rest of the pages shows "NOT Found" and "The requested URL /apk-download/ was not found on this server."

Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at www.frpbypass.us Port 80
URL: [http://www.frpbypass.us][1]

I have tried to change:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Also, added the WordPress default .httaccess.

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

After making the changes, I have restarted the Apache web server as well as Server reboot.

Any idea of how to fix?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to setting -> permalink and change your default permalink setting twice.

It will change the default htaccess and your site will start working.

Comment: Also, I have noticed it cannot be changed from "Post Name" structure no matter what type of structure I choose and click on save changes it comes again to Post Name.

Comment: will you please send the url of home page and screenshot of admin panel's permalink page ?

Comment: Sure here you go:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nw1-YTdeMxTR7yG3CMEET__mYL1a0spO/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Here is the configuration screenshot:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AXFsCMhsiEgkHdcggz7gdAqXNE-uZZ0-/view?usp=drivesdk

Site URL is already given in the post.

Comment: exactly what error its showing on your pages like 404 or 500 error.

Comment: Page Not Found 404

Comment: UPDATE: Now it's working under WordPress's default but when I changed it back to Post name the same error occurs! Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am able to fix the issue. If you're experiencing the same issue then first just saving the Permalink should fix the issue. If not then try .htaccess method and finally looking for apache2.conf file.

In my case, I made all the changes as above but enabling the apache2 rewrite mod fixed my issue.

Use this command:

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Hope this helps anyone who faces the same issue. It took hours of research to finally fix the issue.